# Example of an Android ListView GreenDroid (GDListActivity)?

Tags: android, listactivity, greendroid

Anyone have an example of an Android ListView GreenDroid (GDListActivity)?

Thanks

Comment: Cant you donwload the project from git hub and import it to eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class MoodleUcTarefasActivity extends GDListActivity {

    private MoodleEventAdapter eventAdapter = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.initActionBar();

        if (eventAdapter == null)
            eventAdapter = new MoodleEventAdapter(this);
        setListAdapter(eventAdapter);

    }

private void initActionBar() {
        setTitle("Your action bar title");
    }
}
```

It's simple. Simple extend the GDListActivity to your activity, and link your adapter to the list.